# Element InnerHTML HTML Entities Unwanted

Tags: javascript

If I grab the innerHTML of an item, it returns the HTML entities for certain characters. If I include 2 consecutive spaces, it includes the first space encoded as space and the space to follow as an HTML entity.

I'm trying to parse words, letters, and numbers from a div and this is creating an issue because it's filling my array with nspb, br, and others.

Is there anyway to get around this behavior?

I am well aware of options such as string.replace, but I would rather avoid it because it would clutter up my code.

Comment: If you're after just the text, look at the [*textContent*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent) property.

Comment: Note that older IE supports *innerText* instead so you might need `text = (element.textContent || element.innerText)`